# A WHILE LOOP in SQL that I want to have loop once with 5 updates through all rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a WHILE LOOP in an SQL query.

I have a table with  5 ROWS matching the counter

I'm randomizing 2048 rows and want to INSERT 1 - 5 over those rows, randomly into a single column but what I'm getting is, the query loops once over 2048 and inserts "1", then it loops a second time and inserts "5", then inserts, "3", then "4", and finally "2".

What I seek is loop through one time through the 2048 rows and insert randomly, 1 - 5 through 2048 rows (1 time) in the single column.

Here's the SQL which works but wrong.

```
declare @counter int
SET @counter = 1
BEGIN TRAN
WHILE (@counter <= 6)
BEGIN
SELECT id, city, wage_level 
    FROM myFirstTable
    ORDER BY NEWID()

    UPDATE myFirstTable
        SET wage_level = @counter
        SET @counter = @counter + 1
    CONTINUE
END
COMMIT TRAN
```

The values in the table that contain 5 rows are irrelevant but fact that the "IDs" in that table are from 1 - 5 "ARE."

I'm close, but no cigar...

The result should be something like this:

```
id-----city------wage_level
---------------------
1      Denver        2
2      Chicago       3
3      Seattle       5
4      Los Angeles   1
5      Boise         4
---
2047   Charleston    2
2048   Rochester     1
```

And so on...

Thanks, everyone

Comment: Your `UPDATE` has no where clause. It just updates every row regardless. Does `myFirstTable` have a unique key? You can use that to pick the row. Or you can use mod (%) to spit out 1-5 based on a number (i.e. `NEWID()`). Then you don't need a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a loop. SQL works best on a set based approach.
Here is one way to do it:

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
CREATE TABLE myFirstTable
(
    id int identity(1,1), 
    city varchar(20), 
    wage_level int
)

INSERT INTO myFirstTable (city) VALUES
('Denver'),
('Chicago'),
('Seattle'),
('Los Angeles'),
('Boise')
```

The update statement:

```
UPDATE myFirstTable 
SET wage_level = (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 5) + 1
```

Check the update:

```
SELECT *
FROM myFirstTable
```

Results:

```
id  city        wage_level
1   Denver      3
2   Chicago     3
3   Seattle     2
4   Los Angeles 4
5   Boise       3
```

Explanation: use [`NEWID()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) to generate a guid, [`CHECKSUM()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx) to get a number based on that guid, [`ABS()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189800.aspx) to get only positive values, `% 5` to get only values between 0 and 4, and finally, `+ 1` to get only values between 1 and 5:

Comment: Zohar, THANK YOU sir. Forgive me about the "skill table", which is created, but since I didn't think it relevent, which I shouldn't do that in the future, I didn't show it here.  Although it's only five rows, the fact remains, I failed to give you all the info.  Thanks again and Happy New Year.

Comment: Glad to help :-). Don't worry about the table, just remember in your future questions to include the relevant tables DDL and DML as sample data so that it would be easier to answer.